# linking to cfml code ala jsfiddle

Tags: coldfusion

ok so i'm working on a new version of cflive.net and one of the features is to link to code.
I am using jsfiddle.net as my inspiration for the new site.
Now with jsfiddle all the code runs in the client, so it is not a problem for other people to edit it.
But with CFML obviously the files need to be saved on the server first, which means the original file would get overwritten if anyone makes any changes, which is obviously going to be problematic as the original author may not want his files to get edited, so I am looking for some feedback/suggestions on what would be the best way to handle this.

My best idea so far is.

All files are stored in a unique folder using a JsessionID
e.g. anonymous files
/jsessionid/filename.cfm
or user files
/user/jsessionid/filename.cfm

the original author marks the files as editable or not. You must register and be logged in to have this control.
Files created anonymously (not logged in) can be edited as default.

If the file is editable then it can be edited, otherwise it gets duplicated for each new session.
Anonymous sessions get deleted if they have not been access for 90 days.

thoughts?

Comment: How do gists on Github.com work? If you make changes, doesn't it get a new I'd for the gist?

Comment: When you talk about files, I assume you mean the code is saved to disk and then executed from disk? Could you save the code to a database instead and then drop it in a temp file to execute it? You might find it easier to manage versions of code in the db.

Comment: Gists are git repos - they have an unchanging ID and a revision history. Other users can fork them (which presumably gives a new ID but provides links between the two).

Comment: Also, using existing mature well-tested version control software (i.e. git) to manage this would be a trillion times better than hacking together a database-based re-invention of version control.

Comment: sadly not had much time to work on this, so it still did not go live yet. The version I have so far works, but I am thinking to just leverage GIT instead and just use their API to generate gists for everything and just pull the files from github each time and generate temp sessions for each gist.